# Does Ruby on Rails enable PostGIS for you?

Tags: postgis, installation, ruby

When using PostGIS with Ruby on Rails and the rgeo - activerecord PostGIS adapter

Do I need to create a database first in PostgreSQL and enable the PostGIS extension?

Comment: GIS SE utilizes a "Focused question / Best Answer" model. Please **edit** your question to contain exactly one question.  There are formatting tools in the desktop editor interface to make your question more legible; please use them.

Comment: Your most recent edit did more harm than good. Please *increase* clarity with edits by including versions of software involved and what steps you have taken to discover the answer on your own.

Answer (score 4):

No, as you set up your Rails application it will install the extension when it creates your database.  I'm pretty sure however, you will need to be using versions of Postgres & PostGIS that support the CREATE EXTENSION method of installing extensions.

In order to use PostGIS you'll need to instruct your application to use the PostGIS ActiveRecord adapter.

First step is to make sure you use Postgres, so specify it as you create your application:

```
rails new application_name --database=postgresql
```

In your Gemfile add the PostGIS ActiveRecord adapter

```
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'
```

And to use it in your config/database.yml change the adapter from postgresql to postgis

```
 adapter: postgis
```

Now you're ready to create your database through rails:

```
rails db:create
```

And add the PostGIS extension:

```
rails db:gis:setup
```

I use [this blogpost](http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2014/05/18/postgis-and-google-maps-in-rails-part-1/) as a guide when I want to set up a new PostGIS Rails application.